# How to edit bad word filter in SpamAssassin?

Tags: email, spamassassin, spam-filter

How can I add several custom "bad" words into SpamAssassin, so emails that contains that words are marked as a spam?

**UPDATE**

one of the keys is to edit file /etc/mail/spamassassin, and to add badword filter as described on

http://linuxguruz.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/spamassassin-example/

BUT, in this case, mail is only marked as a spam, it still goes to my Inbox...

What do I have to do, to not receive emails that contains bad words at all?

**UPDATE 2**

My SpamAssassin does change subject if email is classified as a Spam, and it works fine now. File /etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf looks like this:

```
ok_locales all
skip_rbl_checks 0

required_score 5
report_safe 1
rewrite_header Subject ***SPAM***

use_pyzor 1
use_razor2 1

use_auto_whitelist 0


use_bayes 1
use_bayes_rules 1
bayes_auto_learn 1
blacklist_from *@kupiizaradi.cjb.net
blacklist_from *@hallmark.com
whitelist_from *@*hrgworldwide.com
whitelist_from *@bluehost.com
#blacklist_from *@greekajob.com

header CONTAINS_VIG Subject =~ /viagra, Cialix Pills, sex, xxx, penis, pussy, greekajob, greekajobs, pera
zdera/
body CONTAINS_PEN /viagra, sex, xxx, penis, puss, greekajob, greekajobs, perazdera/
score CONTAINS_VIG 1.5
score CONTAINS_PEN 1.5
describe CONTAINS_VIG Bad Word
describe CONTAINS_PEN Bad Word
```

So, now I need help how to:

1. move those emails into Spam folder
2. automatically create Spam folder for every new mail account added on server

File /etc/mail/mailfilter looks like this:

```
SHELL="/bin/sh"
import EXT
import HOST
VHOME=`pwd`
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%b %d %H:%M:%S"`
#VERBOSE=9

logfile "/var/log/maildrop/maildrop.log"
log "$TIMESTAMP - BEGIN maildrop processing for $EXT@$HOST ==="

`test -r $VHOME/.mailfilter`
if($RETURNCODE == 0)
{
    log "including $VHOME/.mailfilter"
    exception {
        include $VHOME/.mailfilter
    }
}


# does maildirsize exist?
`test -e $VHOME/Maildir/maildirsize`

# if maildirsize doesn't exist
if($RETURNCODE == 1)
{ 

    # does vuserinfo exist?
    `test -x /home/vpopmail/bin/vuserinfo` 

    # if vuserinfo exists
    if($RETURNCODE == 0)
    { 
        # does the user exist?
        `/home/vpopmail/bin/vuserinfo $EXT@$HOST`
        if($RETURNCODE == 0)
        {

            # find out what the user's quota is
            $QUOTA=`/home/vpopmail/bin/vuserinfo -Q $EXT@$HOST`
            log "QUOTA = $QUOTA"

            # does maildirmake exists?
            `test -x /usr/bin/maildirmake`

            # if maildirmake exists
            if($RETURNCODE == 0)
            {

                # does Maildir exist?
                `test -d $VHOME/Maildir`

                # if Maildir exists
                if($RETURNCODE == 0)
                {

                    # make the maildirsize file
                    `/usr/bin/maildirmake -q $QUOTA $VHOME/Maildir`
                    `test -s "$VHOME/Maildir/maildirsize"`

                    # if maildirsize exists
                    if($RETURNCODE == 0)
                    {
                        `/bin/chown vpopmail:vchkpw $VHOME/Maildir/maildirsize`
                        `/bin/chmod 640 $VHOME/Maildir/maildirsize`

                    # else 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log "Problem making 'maildirsize' for $VHOME"
                    }

                    # end if maildirsize exists
                }
                else
                {
                    log "Maildir does not exist for $VHOME"
                }

                # end if Maildir exists
            }
            else
            {
                log "maildirmake does not exist"

            # end if maildirmake exists
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log "user $EXT@HOST does not exist"

        # end if user exists
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log "vuserinfo does not exist"

    # end if vuserinfo exists
    }
}
# does maildirsize exist?
`test -e $VHOME/Maildir/maildirsize`
if($RETURNCODE == 0)
{
    MAILDIRQUOTA=`/usr/bin/head -n1 $VHOME/Maildir/maildirsize`
    log "MAILDIRQUOTA = $MAILDIRQUOTA"
}


#--------------------------------------------------------
# Filter spam - scores >= SPAMLIMIT is not delivered
#
# If you DO NOT want to send mail that is over the spam limit
# to spamassassin autolearn, comment: 'cc "|sa-learn -spam"'
#--------------------------------------------------------

##########################################################################
# Below is where I found some of the main problem, i.e apparently the
# regex logic changed, do a diff against this one and the old one,
# the old one was delimited with the '!' (bang) and grouped as a whole.
# it failed the match always.  By using standard regex grouping, I was able
# to get the filter working. By grouping the score accordingly, it
# breaks it into a number and precision, e.g. MATCH1 and MATCH2
##########################################################################

if(/^X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/:h)
{
    if($MATCH1 >= 5)
    {
        cc "|sa-learn --spam"
    }

    # if the user doesnt' have a Spam folder
    `test -d $VHOME/Maildir/.Spam`
    if($RETURNCODE == 1)
    {
        `test -x /usr/bin/maildirmake`
        if($RETURNCODE == 0)
        {
            `/usr/bin/maildirmake -f Spam $VHOME/Maildir`
            `test -x /usr/bin/subscribeIMAP.sh`
            if($RETURNCODE == 0)
            {
                `/usr/bin/subscribeIMAP.sh Spam $VHOME`
            }
        }
    }

    # make sure the deliverquota binary exists and is executable
    `test -x /usr/bin/deliverquota`
    if($RETURNCODE == 1)
    {
        exception {
            to "$VHOME/Maildir/.Spam"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cc "|/usr/bin/deliverquota -w 90 $VHOME/Maildir/.Spam"
        if($RETURNCODE == 0)
        {
            log "=== END ===  $EXT@$HOST  success (quota)"
            EXITCODE=0
            exit
        }
        else
        {
            if($RETURNCODE == 77)
            {
                log "$TIMESTAMP - $EXT@$HOST  bounced (quota)"
                to "|/var/qmail/bin/bouncesaying '$EXT@$HOST is over quota'"
            }
            else
            {
                log \
                 "$TIMESTAMP - $EXT@$HOST failure (unknown deliverquota error)"
                to "$VHOME/Maildir/.Spam"
            }
        }
    }
}

##########################################################################
# Same as above
##########################################################################
if(/^X-Spam-Status: No, score=([\-]*[0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) /:h)
{
    log "   message is clean ($MATCH1.$MATCH2)"
}


#--------------------------------------------------------
# Include any user rules 
#--------------------------------------------------------

`test -r $VHOME/Maildir/.mailfilter`
if($RETURNCODE == 0)
{
    log "   including $VHOME/Maildir/.mailfilter"
    exception {
        include $VHOME/Maildir/.mailfilter
    }
}

`test -x /usr/bin/deliverquota`
if ($RETURNCODE == 1)
{
    log "$TIMESTAMP - $EXT@$HOST WARNING: no deliverquota!"
    log "=== END ===  $EXT@$HOST success"
    exception {
        to "$VHOME/Maildir"
    }
}
else
{
    exception {
        log "RETCODE = $RETURNCODE   delivering to $VHOME/Maildir"
        xfilter "/usr/bin/deliverquota -w 90 $VHOME/Maildir"
    }
    #--------------------------------------------------------
    # check to make sure the message was delivered
    # returncode 77 means that out maildir was overquota - bounce mail
    #--------------------------------------------------------
    if($RETURNCODE == 77)
    {
        log "$TIMESTAMP - BOUNCED: bouncesaying '$EXT@$HOST is over quota'"
        log "$TIMESTAMP - $EXT@$HOST  bounced"
        to "|/var/qmail/bin/bouncesaying '$EXT@$HOST is over quota'"
    }
    else
    {
        log "=== END ===  $EXT@$HOST  success (quota)"
        EXITCODE=0
        exit
    }
}

log "$TIMESTAMP - $EXT@$HOST - WARNING: This message should never be printed!"
[root@um-1027 /etc/mail]#
```

And .qmail-default looks like this:

```
|/var/qmail/bin/preline /usr/bin/maildrop /etc/mail/mailfilter
```

Can you help me please how to fix this and to move spam messages into spam folder?

Comment: `/viagra, sex, xxx, penis, puss, greekajob, greekajobs, perazdera/` a logical OR is not a comma. It's a pipe. = "|". Commas are usually taken as literal commas and spaces the same. You are searching for one line exactly like this in body:  "viagra, sex, xxx, penis, puss, greekajob, greekajobs, perazdera". Try `/(viagra|sex|xxx|penis|puss.|greekajob|greekajobs|perazdera)/i` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In SpamAssassin you can create rules that appends N score to the spam classification header after it's triggered.

It's up to yourself to set the threshold for when it's to be classified as spam, and what to do with it (delete, move to folder, forward?, etc).

If you want to move suspected spam mails to a specific folder I suspect you to hook it into your POP3/IMAP server (ex: dovecot), or POP3/IMAP client usage (ex: fetchmail + procmail).

## Dovecot example using sieve scripts:

`if header :contains "X-Spam-Level" "**********" {
  discard;
  stop;
}`

Ref: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Direct_filtering_using_message_header

## Procmail rule to filter spam to SPAM folder (~/.procmailrc)

`:0:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
SPAM`

Ref: https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/procmail-spam.html

I hope this proves helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With SpamAssassin you just can rewrite a mail detected as a spam but you can't delete it. Postfix or cpanel use SpamAssassin for detect  spams not for handle it. But you can create a rules in cpanel (for example) for delete email with a title rewrite by SpamAssassin. In my opinion, it's a bad idea, you can miss false positive. Just put it on a specific folder with a basic rule.

Comment: You're right, because I did manage to rewrite subject (and body), and to mark proper emails as a spam. Can you point me how to manage to automatically move those messages into spam folder (for every email account)? I don't have Cpanel, server is under my maintenance.

Comment: Since I have some updates regarding this problem, I modified a bit my question...

Comment: Looks like email does not "reach" /etc/mail/mailfilter script in case it is spam... Looks like something deletes it before it reach it. In case mail is not spam, everything works fine...

Comment: If you are using doveco as pop/imap server ýou can use sieve to move spam tagged mails to a separate spam folder, bypassing inbox

Answer (score 0):

Moving messages has nothing to do with Spamassassin and is entirely dependent on your LDA or MUA (Local Delivery Agent or Mail user Agent). Is your mail being delivered to a POP3 account, an IMAP account? is your server using Dovecot or Cyrus or something else?

Too many questions and variables, and this is not the place for those questions.